# PHP Adding file paths to Database

Tags: php, mysql

i have put together this script to load file paths from my uploaded files to the database. But it doesn't seem to work. Please any suggestions are great. Its basically for a simple form that allows multiple file uploads. I need to sen this info to the database with the file paths for later use.
I get an output warning of 
This is a simple test to check if the variables are actually posted

Here is the echo $sql;

```
 INSERT INTO mediamanagement ( `Project_Name`, `Assigned_To`, `Assign_Date`, `Check_Date`, `Due_Date` ) VALUES ( "fvfg df fdh bdfgb", "Ramon", "2013-04-01", "2013-04-18", "2013-04-30", Error:You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 13
        Error:You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 13
```

heres the php:

```
<?php
mysql_connect("MySQLB15.wer.com","york","usa12") or die ('Error:' .mysql_error());
//database connection
    mysql_select_db("mediamanagement");

$project = $_POST['project'];
$assignto = $_POST['assignto'];
$asdate = $_POST['asdate'];

$chdate = $_POST['chdate'];
$ddate = $_POST['ddate'];



$errors = array();
$files = array();
foreach ($_FILES['files'] as $k=>$image) {

    // handle upload errors
    if ($image['error'] != 0 && $image['error'] != 4) {         
        switch ($image['error']) {
            case '1':
            case '2':
                $err = 'The uploaded file exceeds the maximum file size.';
                break;                  
            case '3':
                $err = 'The upload was inturupted, transfer failed.';
                break;
            case '6':
            case '7':
            case '8':
                $err = 'Server error.  Please try again later.';
                break;
        }
        // record error and move on
        $errors[] = array('files'=>$k, 'error'=>$err);
        continue;
    } elseif ($image['error'] == 4) {
        // error 4 means no image was sent
        continue;
    }

    // determine the extension
    $ext = explode('.', $image['name']);
    if (count($ext) != 2) {
        $errors[] = array('files'=>$k, 'error'=>'Could not determine file extension.');
        continue;
    } else {
        switch ($ext[1]) {
            case 'jpg':
            case 'jpeg':
            case 'gif':
            case 'png':
            case 'pdf':
            case 'psd':
            case 'ai':
            case 'pdf':


                break;
            default:
                $errors[] = array('files'=>$k, 'error'=>'Unsupported file extension.');
                continue;
                break;
        }
    }

    // make a random-ish filename
    $filename = time().uniqid(rand(), true) . '.' . $ext[1];
    $path = 'uploads/'.$filename;   // upload directory path is set

    move_uploaded_file($image['tmp_name'], $path);     //  upload the file to the server
    // this is a bad idea right here! Use 775 at least, if possible
    chmod($path,0775);
    $files[] = array('name'=>$filename, 'path'=>$path);
}

// now loop the $files array and put the paths into the database

// you also should do something with the errors listed in $errors
// start building up the SQL query, start with
// some fields that are straightforward


$sql = '
    INSERT INTO mediamanagement (
       `Project_Name`,
        `Assigned_To`,
        `Assign_Date`,
        `Check_Date`,
        `Due_Date`';

// now loop the list of files (5 only), 
// add each needed field

for ($i=1; $i < count($files) && $i < 5; $i++) {
    $sql .= '`files'.$i.'`,';
}

// build out the rest of the query, add values
// for the straightforward fields
$sql .= '

) VALUES (
    "'.$project.'", 
    "'.$assignto.'",
    "'.$asdate.'",
    "'.$chdate.'",
     "'.$ddate.'",
';



// loop the files
$ct = 1;
foreach ($files as $f) {
    $sql .= '"'.$f['name'].'",';
    // only allow 5 files
    if ($ct == 5)
        break;
    $ct++;
}
 ')';




mysql_query($sql) or die ('Error:' .mysql_error());;





?>

<?php
echo("<p><span>Project Name:</span> ".$_POST['project']."</p>");
echo("<p><span>assign to:</span> ".$_POST['assignto']."</p>");
echo("<p><span>Assign Date:</span> ".$_POST['asdate']."</p>");
echo("<p><span>Check Date:</span> ".$_POST['chdate']."</p>");
echo("<p><span>Due Date:</span> ".$_POST['ddate']."</p>");



?>
```

Comment: Print out your final SQL syntax and check it for errors.

Comment: You posted so much code...but did not post the ONE thing required. Result of `echo $sql;`

Comment: Escape your POST parameters. Your code is susceptible to SQL injection.

Comment: Before you do anything else, read up on [SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/) because you're creating a whole mess of trouble for yourself here. You **cannot** write code like this. You must [properly escape](http://bobby-tables.com/php) any and all user data added to a query. Using `mysql_query` is also an extremely bad idea.

Comment: Will do about reading up on sql escaping and no more using deprecating code. I'm still a noob and eating up as much knowledge of PHP as possibe. Any ideas s to how to go about making this work and load up my daabse?

Comment: I really need some suggestions in the right direction as to what I am doing wrong here. please.

Answer (score 0):

trouble there

```
for ($i=1; $i < count($files) && $i < 5; $i++) {
  $sql .= '`files'.$i.'`,';
}
than
) VALUES (

and we got ',) VALUE(
```

Comment: I think your formatting is wrong because this doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Please le me know what's wrongfully formatted. I'm still beginner and learning

Comment: anybody can help a noob out please?

Answer (score -1):

make a dump of your sql query and post it 
btw. i dont think, you are knowing what you do ... and just copy and past some code owned by an other

Comment: When the dump is correct ... you forget to close the ")" of VALUES and the last "," in the VALUES-statement is not correct ...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: ok I understand tat I have to close the Values wit this ")" but what do you mean about the VALUES-statamet is not correct?

Comment: in your FIELDS you give 5 fields ... in the VALUES (...) the 5th statement is  "2013-04-30",  the "," is worong in this case because the last value has no "," and and by an ')' to close the VALUES

Comment: could you post an example?